# Can you save up skill points to spend on a later tier?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

In Etrian Odyssey 4, there seem to be three tiers of skills: Novice, Veteran, and Master. I'm not allowed to buy skills in the Veteran tier until level 20, and Master even later than that.

I'm trying to plan out my party's builds and would like to know if I can save up skill points during levels 1-20 so that I can dump them all in the Veteran tier once I unlock it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Many of the Veteran and Master skills require skills in the novice and Veteran tier respectively. So if you've unlocked the skill by spending points in the previous tier, then yes, feel free to save points and dump them into higher tier skills.

Alternatively, in this iteration of the game you only lose 2 levels when you reset your characters. So feel free to spend all your points and reset them later on to dump the points into higher tier skills.